# SQLPLUS withing shell script loops

Tags: shell, scripting, sql

Hello I am trying to run a loop and get the details of a project. I have these projects in my work space. How do I loop over the SQL code?

```
#!/bin/bash


    workspace=$(sudo locate -r '/workspace$')
    cd $workspace
    echo "" > ~/Desktop/workspace.txt
    for projectName in `ls -d *`;
    do
        echo $projectName >> ~/Desktop/workspace.txt
    done

    cat workspace.txt | while read Name
    sqlplus $1/$2 <<ENDOFSQL > ~/Desktop/$Name.txt
    DESC PROJECTS;
    SELECT ID_NAME, VALUE FROM PROJECTS WHERE ID_NAME='%${Name}%';
    exit;
    ENDOFSQL

    echo "Testing"
```

When I run it, I get the error

```
./sql_parameters.sh: line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two things:

while should be in this form

```
while condition; do
    your code from while
done
```

also, make sure ENDOFSQL is from new line and there are no spaces between.